# How to call constructor from template?

Tags: angular

Having a template such as:

```
  <button (click)="navigateTo(???)">Today</button>
```

How would it be possible to construct a `new Date()` as the argument? I'd rather not have a separate function just to return the date, and neither a specialized handler for today `navigateToToday`, or the alike.

Comment: You could interpret no argument (`undefined`) as meaning today.

Comment: Yeah, I mean that's what I wound up with as well, but I encounter this issue here and there,and was wondering if there was an actual way to do this without hacks like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default value for params in javascript, PFB example!

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <button (click)="navigateTo()">Today</button>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  navigateTo(param: Date = new Date()) {
    alert(param);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-5xt52p)

Comment: Yeah, I mean that's what I wound up with as well, but I encounter this issue here and there,and was wondering if there was an actual way to do this without hacks like this.

Comment: @ÁkosVandra-Meyer no it's a limitation you need to do hacks for it to work